# privately encapsulate its object data

Tags: javascript, tdd, jasmine

Please Advise. Completing http://testfirst.org/learn_javascript - stuck on 07_temperature last spec:

Here is my code:

```
function Temperature(value){

this.fahrenheit = function(){
    if(this.fahrenheit_value===undefined){
        this.fahrenheit_value = Math.fround(this.celsius_value*1.8 + 32,2);
    }
    return this.fahrenheit_value;
};

this.setFahrenheit = function(value){
    this.fahrenheit_value = value;
};

this.celcius = function(){
    if(this.celsius_value===undefined){
        this.celsius_value = Math.round((this.fahrenheit_value-32)/1.8);
    }
    return this.celsius_value;
};

this.setCelcius= function(value){
 this.celsius_value = value;
};
}
```

And the spec I am trying to pass is as follows, I am not sure how to pass the last one "privately encapsulates its data".

```
describe("the Temperature object", function() {
    it("privately encapsulates its data", function() {
        var temperature;
        temperature = new Temperature(32);
        for (var property in temperature) {
            // This assures that there are no data values at all on the object, just methods
          console.log(temperature[property]);
          expect(typeof(temperature[property])).toEqual('function');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So are you saying that your code, as presented, does not pass this spec?  It looks like it should.  Every property of Temperature is a function.

Comment: The test does not pass - did you try running the code?